# HTMLAgilityPack XPath Expression not fetching all nodes

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

**Scope**
I am trying to parse [this page](https://uspdigital.usp.br/jupiterweb/listarGradeCurricular?codcg=12&codcur=12012&codhab=1&tipo=N). For those who are not familiar with portuguese, this page contains all the Subjects from a certain Course (university course), grouped by "Semester".

So, everytime you see something like this "7º Período Ideal", you can understand like "Subjects
from the 7th semester".

**Problem** I am using a XPath expression to get all the Table Rows from the table that contains those table rows.

```
XPath Used : //table[@cellspacing=2]//tr

C# Statement : htmlMap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@cellspacing=2]//tr");
```

The HtmlNodeCollection received by this C# statement, contains only the table row nodes until the one with this text `EAD0648    Gerência de Produtos / Serviços e Mercados`, right after the one with `5º Período Ideal`.

This XPath "works", but i get all the `tr's`(as it is  expected), and this is not what i want.

```
//tr
```

Why is the XPath not retrieving all the nodes after this node aswell ?

Is there any cap of ammount of nodes retrieved ?
Am i missing something ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you reduce it to the smallest html document possible that still reproduces the problem and then add that document to the text of your question?  The link may be helpful, but it won't do much good to a visitor of Stack Overflow years from now if that link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: The HTML is huge =/
I may post it to pastebin

Comment: You can't reduce it to a smaller sample that still has the problem?

Comment: The shortest one, would lead to over 700 lines of copy and paste

Comment: I haven't looked at it in depth, but it does seem odd that shortly after the EAD0648 row, it has sub rows that have ending TR tags, but seemingly no opening TR tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered this in the past, if the tables are not well formed then issues like this occur. I took a very quick look at the HTML for the page and I see what looks like a possible problem, on line 2785 there is a `</tr>` then without a opening `<tr>` line 2796 has another `</tr>`.

I admit that I did not do an in depth validation to check, but just by looking at it I could not match the opening `<tr>`. I immediately checked this because as I mentioned I have faced this exact issue with pages with malformed tables.